# Making two HTML buttons go side by side

Tags: html, button

Okay, I'm not very familiar with HTML, or how it comes together with CSS. I have been looking all over on how to make two HTML buttons go side by side. Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="LINK TO WEBSITE" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Forum Home Page">
</FORM>
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="LINK TO A DIFFERENT WEBSITE" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Skill Guides">
</FORM>
```

No matter if I put them right after each other or put an alignment infront of them. I can't seem to get them to go next to each other. I hope there is someone that can easily and in a detailed way, help me out.

Comment: why use forms? you can have javascript do it for you

Comment: Why use forms or JavaScript when you actually want to link? You can always style a link to look like a button if you like.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand you correctly, you can just attach the following CSS:

```
form {
    display: inline;
}
```

As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/zcz3j/

Comment: Well, How would I implement that? Just right after the two FORM tags?

Answer (score 0):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/satinder_singh1/wr4Xv/1/

```
<div id="main">
<div class="floatdiv"><FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="LINK TO WEBSITE" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Forum Home Page">
</FORM></div>
<div class="floatdiv">
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="LINK TO A DIFFERENT WEBSITE" target="_blank">
  <input type="submit" value="Skill Guides">
    </FORM></div></div>​

<style type="text/css">
    #main
    {
    position:relative;
        width:200px;
    }

    .floatdiv
    {
    float:left;
        width=80px
    }
</style>
```

​

Comment: As i said, I still haven't quite understood how both HTML an CSS are set together. Please consider.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try wrapping them in a table tag. That's how I fixed my similar issue. The table automatically set them side by side.